# How to run the application in the background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Iam doing one application.In that i want to run the my application in the background.So how to write the code for that.Please tell me because iam very new for this technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general answer is, you can not run your application while in background, except certain cases.

Doc says,

> Most applications that enter the background state are moved to the suspended state shortly thereafter. While in this state, the application does not execute any code and may be removed from memory at any time. Applications that provide specific services to the user can request background execution time in order to provide those services.

So only some specific services like **audio, location and voip** services can execute in background. Read this [`Executing Code in the Background`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW4) doc for more detail regarding the background services.

Comment: Sir is there any possible for getting the x,y,z axis values in the background

Comment: @naresh, It is not possible, Sir

Comment: @naresh, Why do you want to get the accelerometer values while your app is in background?

Comment: That is my requirment sir.Compare the every value with default value and if any value cross the default value then notification rise.

Comment: - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
 UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{       [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;}];
 // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
UIAcceleration *acceleration=[[UIAcceleration alloc]init];
float r=acceleration.x;
  NSLog(@"%f",r);
if((r >= [babycrydefault floatForKey:@"keyToSlidervalue"]))

Answer (score 2):

You can use appDeleagte function.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

}
```

Comment: id localNotif = [[NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification") alloc] init];
    if (!localNotif) {
        return;
    }
[localNotif setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

[localNotif setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];