# How can I use local notifications to wake my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i want that my app will run in the background and do check on somethings.
and if so the local notification will show.

i use this code in the method that check:

```
UIApplication *app                = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSArray *oldNotifications         = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];

if ([oldNotifications count] > 0) {
    [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}

if (notification == nil)
    return;

NSDate *notificationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];

notification.fireDate  = notificationDate;
notification.timeZone  = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
notification.alertBody = @"Test Body";

[app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

[notification release];
```

the problem is that when the app is in the foreground it show the alert, but if the app is in the background the notification not show to the screen.

the check that i do is running on uiwebview and reload every 10 seconds, so he need to run in the background too.

Comment: how to enable the app keep run in the background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app won't run in background, except certain cases. Look in to this [**How to run the application in the background?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420866/how-to-run-the-application-in-the-background/6421068#6421068) post.