# I wanted to make an http call when my iphone application goes to the background

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I wanted to make an http call when my application is running in the background where i am trying to download multiple files. Is it possible to achieve this task. If available can anyone provide me with a sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6420866/491980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the application is in the background it will usually be suspended.  So you will not be able to download data continuously in the background.

If your task is limited you could try implementing `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`.  This will allow you to ask the system for extra time to perform the remainder of the task in the background.

You can take a look at the documentation provided by Apple to further understand how it is done.

[Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: i was able to achieve it. i was able to download for another 10 minutes after bringing my application to the background, after that i need to relaunch the app. But will there be any scenario where my application get removed from the memory while it is running in the background.

Comment: Yes, when memory becomes low your app can be removed by the system.