# Is it possible to trigger capture the arrival or delivery of IOS LocalNotification If it the app is not running

Tags: ios, sdk

Is it possible to  capture the arrival or delivery of IOS LocalNotification. So that I can do some actions

Comment: No, delivery of a local notification does not execute any code in your app.  You should look at the background fetch capability

Answer (score 0):

Your app won't run in background, except certain cases. Look in to this [How to run the application in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420866/how-to-run-the-application-in-the-background/6421068#6421068) post.

Comment: Mohammad  my application may even be running . I want to  trigger  custom code to fetch some details periodically